# profileId ga:XXXXXXXX has exceeded the daily request limit

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Hi I am trying to extract the `ga` data from `rga` package.

```
 id <- XXXXXXXX 
 start_index <- 1 
 device_visits <- ga$getData(id, start.date= start_date, end.date=end_date, metrics = "ga:sessions", dimensions="ga:deviceCategory",batch=TRUE, start=start_index)
```

I was doing this successfully until I had an error

```
 Error in ga$getData(id, start.date = start_date, end.date = end_date,  : 
 error in fetching data: Quota Error: profileId ga:XXXXXXXXX has exceeded the daily request limit.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Wait until tomorrow. You exceeded the daily limit, there isn't a way around Google's limits.

Comment: I haven't run a single query today! successfully  but it pops up this error !

Comment: If Google tells you that you exceeded the daily request limit, then you did. Nothing else we can help you with.

Comment: to the -1's its a valid question he didn't make any requests today. Its also doesn't say in the error message that it resets USA time someone who is not in the USA would find it hard to understand that the quota is still blown.

Comment: To the close voters: This question is not about "about general computing hardware and software"  Its about usage of the Google Analytics API.  He posted his code in R.  This is a programing question.

Comment: @DaImTo This has nothing to do we programming. The R code works. The issue is on the server side which is that OP is trying to violate Google TOS. There is nothing you can do in order to solve this programatically unless you will violate the TOS. Your answer doesn't contain any code neither, so not sure what you talking about.

Comment: This is an error with accessing the API.  You don't think API access errors are coding related?  You think he will find help on super user for this?   There are a lot of questions on stack with error messages like this that will be closed then.  https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Google+Analytics+quota+error+stack   Not all answers on stack contain code check my top answer wall of text that one.  No code.

Comment: I don't consider RTFM/RTOS as programming question, sorry.

Comment: See the [help page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors) about errors. About quotas see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas). Also you should try use own client id and client secret that don't share a quotas with other projects.

Comment: @DalmTo I figured the error. It was due to storing the ga data in file to access it. Once I cleared the file and started a fresh query, I got it running. David I completely believe and second you that this not a program error in R. It either had to be sorted out in GA or from removing a file. Since the ga account was fine and up and running, I tried clearing the file and running fresh. Alas it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Analytics API quota for a view is 10000 requests per day.   This is not project based this is total.  Any usage of this view will count against the 10000.

- Using the website
- Using the mobile app
- requests by your application

Everything counts against this quota.  It is also not User based so if you have coworkers with access to this view they are also using this quota.

> I haven't run a single query today! successfully but it pops up this
>   error !

The quota will reset at midnight west cost USA time.   When you posted this it was still yesterday.  Until then you will not be able to access this view.

Your only recourse is to reduces the number of requests you are making tomorrow / today / ...